# Sending Multiple select to server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using a form with multiple selects (using Select2) and submitting the data to the server using HTML5's Formdata object. It works well when I am sending text or files but does not work in this case.

I have given the name attribute as lbl[] as required and also specified multiple="multiple".

Does Formdata support multiple select or is there anything I am missing?

My select:

```
<select class="form-control theread_p_ip" name="thread_p[]" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%"></select>
```

The way I am using Formdata:

```
 form_data = new FormData($(mydata.sform)[0]);
 ajaxoptions.data=form_data;
```

where ajaxoptions is the object I am passing to JQuery AJAX and $(mydata.sform)[0] selects my form

I have checked using `print_r($_POST,true)` and I get this:

```
Array
(
[thread_p] => 
[thread_lbl] => giggg
[ddemand] => json
[dtype] => json
[eltarget] => -1
[sform] => #ta-tbxnewthread
[mkey] => tbx_newthread
)
```

You can see that the thread_p is empty. If I specify name="thread_p" instead of using [] I get the last selected value alone.

PS: Ignore the other values in the array. Those are other parameters I am sending from the client side.

And if you wonder there is no options in select, they are loaded via AJAX by select2 which is working properly.

**UPDATE:** SOLVED using hackerman's fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/95khdzp2/1/

And in server side you get the values separated by ',' which you have to separate using `explode(',', $variable);` if you are using PHP

Comment: `ajaxoptions.data.mySelect2=$(".theread_p_ip").val();` ??

Comment: Nope. select2 is just a plugin I am using. http://select2.github.io/  there is no variable data.mySelect2

Comment: Did you even try..or maybe you already solved it??

Comment: I tried. It does not work.

Comment: Maybe you are doing it wrong: https://jsfiddle.net/95khdzp2/1/ ...just check the console

Comment: @Hackerman: I am testing it with your code.. Will get back to you asap

Comment: @Hackerman: I followed your fiddle and it works.. Thanks. The main change I had to do is use the change event to update the value as you have specified. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow this logic:

```
var ajaxOptions = {};
ajaxOptions.data = {};
$(function(){
  $(".theread_p_ip").select2();

  $(".theread_p_ip").change(function(){
    ajaxOptions.data.mySelect2 = $(this).val();
    console.log(ajaxOptions);
  });
});
```

On this way, your `ajaxOptions` `Object` could update his values, based on the `select2` changes.

Answer (score 1):

As per select2 documentation, You didn't need to give name array, only give name, here name="thread_p"

As per documentation, there is an example provided,

```
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();

<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

please refer https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: If I dont give the [] notation only one value is send (specified in question). I tested it.

Comment: you try to get the value of select2 multiple with $('.theread_p_ip').val(). you will get the value. I tried it in the example

Comment: Yes. That will give the value but if you need to get it on the server, you need to use [] notation. But if you keep storing all the values onchange in the client side in a variable, then you could send the variable to server without having to worry about [] notation. Thanks anyways.